# Prometheus: Count metric value over a period of time

Tags: prometheus

I don't speak English very well, but I need some advice. I have Prometheus.
How can I calculate the number of downtime for a service over a period of time?
It's my function

```
 irate(ALERTS{job="blackbox", alertstate="firing"}[2h])
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If the metric can have either `0` or `1` values, then the `sum_over_time(metric[d])` calculates the number of `1` values on the specified lookbehind window `d`. For example, `sum_over_time(up[1h])` returns the number of `up` samples with `1` value during the last hour. The number of `0` values then can be calculates as `count_over_time(up[1h]) - sum_over_time(up[1h])`.

If the metric can have other values than `0` and `1`, then Prometheus doesn't provide functions for counting the number of samples with a particular value yet :(

There is another Prometheus-like system, which allows counting the number of raw samples with the given value on the specified lookback window - [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/) (I'm the core developer of this system). It provides [count_eq_over_time](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_eq_over_time) function for this task. For example, the following MetricsQL query returns the number of samples for `some_metric` time series with the value `42` over the last hour:

```
count_eq_over_time(some_metric[1h], 42)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the image you provided, it seems like the value of the metric (say `metric_x`) is 1 when the server is down, otherwise 0.

You can use `sum_over_time(range-vector)` query function to calculate, how many times the value was equal to 1 at a given interval.

The following query calculates the sum of `metric_x` (ie. how many times the `mertic_x` was equal to 1) within the last 5 minutes.

```
sum_over_time(metric_x{job="xxx"}[5m])
```

Similarly, the following query calculates the sum of `metric_x` of a day had a week ago. It's like a range, starting time to ending time.

```
sum_over_time(metric_x{job="xxx"}[1d] offset 1w)
```

References:

- [Range Vector Selectors](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#range-vector-selectors)
- [Offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier)
- [aggregation_over_time()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time)

---

**Update:**

Well If I were you, I would create a [recording rule](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/recording_rules/#recording-rules) for the query and perform `sum_over_time()` on the new metric that the rule created.

```
groups:
  - name: rules
    rules:
    - record: blakbox:ALERTS:irate
      expr:  irate(ALERTS{job="blackbox", alertstate="firing"}[2h])
```

```
sum_over_time(blakbox:ALERTS:irate{job="blackbox", alertstate="firing"}[1d] offset 1w)
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I gave worng information. I don't need a total idle time. I want to calculate how many times the service did not work. It is my function - >>  
   irate(ALERTS{job="blackbox", alertstate="firing"}[2h])

Comment: @ВладимирWolf Updated the answer, take a look.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I create a new metric and then count it. But this does not work for me.          sum_over_time(irate(ALERTS{job="blackbox", alertstate="firing", instance="https://example.com"}[2h]))

Comment: @ВладимирWolf , it won't work, because `sum_over_time()` takes `range_vector` as input. Have you tried the process I mentioned?

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it wrong. I just started learning Prometheus
~~~
 1) I change file prometheus.yml and add in block rule_files:
rule_files:  
  - count.rules.yml

2) I add in file count.rules.yml
groups:
  - name: rules
    rules:
    - record: blakbox:ALERTS:irate
      expr:  irate(ALERTS{job="blackbox", alertstate="firing"}[2h])

3)Reload prometheus and made a request
sum_over_time(blakbox:ALERTS:irate{job="blackbox", alertstate="firing"}[90d])
~~~

Comment: @ВладимирWolf, the process looks good to me. what's is result of query `blakbox:ALERTS:irate` ? and `blakbox:ALERTS:irate{job="blackbox", alertstate="firing"}`? and `blakbox:ALERTS:irate{job="blackbox", alertstate="firing"}[90d]` ? are they showing the value as expected?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to answer, but I could not get a positive response from Prometheus

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Grafana as a visualisation tool. There is the possibility to add an expression to a panel. This would result in a second Metric (in my example below B). This is located in the Query Tab on Edit. You ma need a newer Grafana version (AFAIK it was introduced with v6.x)

[image: Example for your case]